# Get the Change Package ID in MKS from CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, mks

I'm trying to write a script for auto integration in MKS. 
I have created a Change Package from CLI, but now I need to get the **Change Package id** to use it in `si lock` function to lock and check in the members.
It's there a way to get it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this problem :

```
si viewcps --fields=id
```